# Only calling a method if a hash is populated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, conditional-statements

I have an instance variable called

```
@filtered_ratings = params[:ratings].keys
```

However, if `params[:ratings]` is nil and `#keys` is called on it there is an error that is raised. If @filtered_ratings is nil, I want @filtered_ratings to be set to an empty array (or hash). Is there an easy way of doing this without too much code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@filtered_ratings = params[:ratings].keys if params[:ratings].respond_to? :keys
```

***Edit:***

```
 # if params[:ratings] is nil then return []
 @filtered_ratings = params[:ratings].try(:keys) || []
```

Comment: I should have worded that better. If `@filtered_ratings = params[:ratings].keys` is nil, I want @filtered_ratings to be set to an empty array (or hash). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Dylan..if you want `@filtered_ratings` to be set to an empty array, you should use this `@filtered_ratings = (params[:ratings] || {}).keys`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@filtered_ratings = params[:ratings].try(:keys)
```

If `params[:ratings]` is `nil`, it will return `nil` as well (instead of raising error).

Also, you most certainly can call `#keys` on an empty hash (`{}`). But `nil` isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the andand gem, because I'm used to it:

```
@filtered_ratings = params[:ratings].andand.key
```

This will set @filtered_ratings to nil, or the key value--that may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Rails has the `#try`. It looks (to me) like too much trouble to bundle a gem only for this. But if you bundle it anyway... :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If it was for a single usage, I wouldn't. I prefer it for readability and when I'm breaking Demeter's heart, it's much cleaner to me :) I also do enough non-Rails Ruby coding I'm just used to having it around without re-writing the admittedly-trivial, shorter replacement.

Comment: @DaveNewton very interesting gem - I'll remember that for when the time comes.